# Clean URL leads to duplicate URL after migration to another hosting

Tags: uri

I have enabled clean URLs on the site after various article has been published on the site.

But when I migrate from Bluehost VPS to Bluehost Share hosting, the clean URLs is not accessible again. And when I remove `?q=` I will see the enable box, and it has lead to duplicate URL on articles on the site.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly enable/configure Clean URLs, refer to [Configure Clean URLs](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) in the installation guide.

If you're not familiar with Clean URLs yet, I suggest to review that documentation in the installation guide carefully (for the version of Drupal that you're using) and make sure your server is correctly configured before proceeding.

Here is a summary of common steps/issues:

- With Apache HTTPD as web-server, you have to enable `mod_rewrite` and configure the necessary rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file.
- Usually, theses rules are applied automatically, when `mod_rewrite` is enabled. But in some cases, the `AllowOverride` directive is too restrictive to allow this.