# Logins with port numbers not including ports on redirect/login

Tags: 6, users, uri, redirection, cookies

We recently upgraded our site to use Drupal 7. Previously we were using Drupal 6. In the testing phase, the Drupal 7 instance was available at ports 8000 and 8443 of the main domain, while Drupal 6 was on the defaults, i.e.:

- Drupal 6: http://www.example.com
- Drupal 6 secure: https://www.example.com (443)
- Drupal 7: http://www.example.com:8000
- Drupal 7 secure: https://www.example.com:8443

That worked fine for the testing phase; we were able to log in to each site and restrict D7 access to our internal network. Once we went live, we switched the ports, i.e.:

- Drupal 6: http://www.example.com:8000
- Drupal 6 secure: https://www.example.com:8443
- Drupal 7: http://www.example.com
- Drupal 7 secure: https://www.example.com (443)

This is working in terms of production traffic, so the new D7 site is working fine. However, when we try to log in on the old D6 site for reference, we're redirected to and logged in on the D7 site. That is, operating to `https://www.example.com:8443/user` and logging in results in being directed to `https://www.example.com/user/foo/bar`, successfully logged in. Going back to the D6 site (on 8443) shows that we are not logged in there.

I thought it could be related to the cookie domain we were using (`.example.com`), which seemed a stretch, but removing that didn't help. I also thought it might be a base URL problem, though we have no base URL configured. The secure pages base URLs are configured with the port numbers.

Does anyone know or have an idea as to why this is happening?

I have a feeling that it's a simple thing I've overlooked in our configuration.

HTTPS is enforced on both sites by the [Secure Pages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages).

EDIT: we think we narrowed it down to the login form submission. The form appears to be submitted to the main domain, without the port. That's logging us in on the wrong site and preventing us from logging in on the D6 one. Why the form would submit without the port and how to fix it is now the issue.

Comment: OK, OK, but what are you using to enforce https? Module? Apache config? Sorry if you already said that, I just don't see it in the question.

Comment: @Mołot: fairly certain we narrowed down the cause to login form. I don't think it's related to securepages, though it's possible.

Comment: What do you have the base URL in your settings.php set as?

Comment: @burnsjeremy: We've tried multiple things; `$base_url = 'https://www.example.com:8443';`, `$base_url = 'http://www.example.com';`, no base URL, etc.

Comment: And when you made every change you ensured you cleared the cache :) if you didn't the forms or page could be cached for Drupal 7 especially.

Comment: We did, but it's entirely possible we missed the crucial one. I'll give it another pass and make sure the form isn't cached.

Comment: Also, since it is the D6 site that you are trying to accomplish this task on and it may be older, I would check the htaccess file. You may need to crawl back through the configurations of the D6 site to see if you missed anything since from what I can tell the D7 site seems to be working fine. If I'm not mistaken you may even need to change the name of the folder that the site config is in to match the URL for d6, since it doesn't have the new snazzy sites.php that handles aliases, we used to have to make the folder match but it's been a while for me on d6 issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check if anything in this list of typical things might help:

- Check if you get the same problem using another browser. If with another browser it works, then it might be a cookie problem. To solve that, delete the cookie in the browser where you have the problem.
- Make sure "clean urls" is enabled. Refer to "[Clean URL leads to duplicate URL after migration to another hosting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165029/clean-url-leads-to-duplicate-url-after-migration-to-another-hosting/165044?s=1%7C3.9647#165044)" for more details on that.
- Make sure the value of "base_url" is set correctly in your [settings.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=7.x#n248) (for D7) and [settings.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=6.x#n125) (for D6).