# How can I log in as admin to my Commerce-kickstart demo site?

Tags: 7, users, commerce

I am new to Drupal and I have completed the installation process for [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) in my XAMPP environment.

When I try to access the admin page of my sample commerce-kickstart demo eshop, I get an error like so:

> error 403 access denied

I am using the predefined Username (admin) and password and PHP 5.3.6.

Can anyone help me to get logged in as admin?

Answer (score 2):

Check if anything in this list of typical things might help:

- Check if you get the same problem using another browser. If with another browser it works, then it might be a cookie problem. To solve that, delete the cookie in the browser where you have the problem.
- Make sure "clean urls" is enabled. Refer to "[Clean URL leads to duplicate URL after migration to another hosting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165029/clean-url-leads-to-duplicate-url-after-migration-to-another-hosting/165044?s=1%7C3.9647#165044)" for more details on that.
- Make sure the value of "base_url" is set correctly (in your [settings.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=7.x#n248)).

Answer (score 1):

For all Drupal installs you can use /users to /user/login to access login form, unless the paths have been changed.