# Page not found in drupal 7

Tags: views, 7

I am new to Drupal. I added a new content type and a view that points in the google map for the locations I entered

This worked fine in my local site. I implemented the same in the live site. But that gave a `page not found` error for every page and all the pages are redirected to some another unneccessary page.

Please let me know if adding a view can cause this kind of errors.

I used these modules: [Location Map](https://www.drupal.org/project/locationmap), [Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder), [geoPHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/geophp) , [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) and [Geomap](https://www.drupal.org/project/geomap).

Or did this effect occure because of using these modules?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if anything in this list of typical things might help:

- Make sure "clean urls" is enabled. Refer to "[Clean URL leads to duplicate URL after migration to another hosting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165029/clean-url-leads-to-duplicate-url-after-migration-to-another-hosting/165044?s=1%7C3.9647#165044)" for more details on that.
- Make sure the value of "base_url" is set correctly (in your [settings.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=7.x#n248)).

Another option is to check the logs. If you find errors there (like PHP Fatal errors), then try to narrow down that error to the module that causes the error and disable that module (and report it in its issue queue on Drupal.org). If you don't know which module is causing it, then first disable all modules, and enable them one by one again. If at some point the error then comes back, then that must be the problem module causing your problem. Then disable that module again and re-enable all others.

Comment: Hi..thank you for the reply.I checked the logs and found the error that reported as below    "     PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings in ..../../includes/common.inc  at the line that contains code below  $options['attributes']['class'][] = 'active'; "

Comment: I enhanced my answer related to the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

*'Page not found'* is exactly what it refers to. That means that particular url is still not created. There are multiple ways to do that in Drupal 7 depending on your approach.

Since you indicated views, for views you would set the page at `Path:` under the `Page Settings` tab incase a Page Level view is being added.

[Here](https://www.acquia.com/blog/totally-beginner-tutorial-views-drupal-7) is a link that can introduce some of those concepts.

If this does not help, please add the link where you would like to display the view at?

Comment: .Thank you for the reply.I have added \path  for the view in the page settings tab only.I tried that in local which worked fine ..I am facing the issue when i am doing the same in the production site.

Comment: Are you able to share the link that you are trying to load? Additionally a screenshot of the view and the error page would help as well